# How to divide boundingbox in segments with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps

What is an efficient way of building a MySQL query to divide a boundingbox in segments?
Assume I have a database with marker locations that I want to show on a map. To speed things up I want to split the viewport of the map into 6 segments and load 5 markers per segment.

Can I do this in 1 sql query or do I have to make 6 queries/requests?

For example: load markers within latitude 0 - 21 and longitude 0 - 15

`SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 0 AND lat <= 7 AND lng >= 0 and lng <= 7.5 limit 5;
 SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 7 AND lat <= 14 AND lng >= 0 and lng <= 7.5 limit 5;
 SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 14 AND lat <= 21 AND lng >= 0 and lng <= 7.5 limit 5;
SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 0 AND lat <= 7 AND lng >= 7.5 and lng <= 15 limit 5;
 SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 7 AND lat <= 14 AND lng >= 7.5 and lng <= 15 limit 5;
 SELECT * FROM markers WHERE lat >= 14 AND lat <= 21 AND lng >= 7.5 and lng <= 15 limit 5`

[image]